# Using @classmethod with @property

Tags: python

I just wondering is it possible to make something like this:

```
class Base:
    __interface__ = BaseInterface        

    @classmethod
    @property
    def interface(cls):
        return cls.__interface__(cls)
```

The goal is to have some interface available both as static and instance variable. But the problem is that this interface should be initialized on class constructor.

Comment: I think the duplicate should answer your question. If it doesn't please [edit] your question and explain **why it doesn't solve your problem** so it can be reopened.